# what does joint_state_controller read?

Tags: ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm fairly new to ros_control and I'm really confused about what are the data joint_state_controller acquires from the Robot's Encoders, are they ticks, ticks per meter or rad? and if it was ticks, where can I provide the Radius of the wheels to the Controller?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321078/what-does-joint_state_controller-read?/) by [zoidberg2010eaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/40045/zoidberg2010eaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm really confused about what are the data joint_state_controller acquires from the Robot's Encoders

To start (and this is slightly pedantic), but `joint_state_controller` (JSC) does not read from your *robot's encoders*. It retrieves *joint state* through something called a [JointStateInterface](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/6616d1d1a5d0a19f482137c5e84e646f01c72e46/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/joint_state_interface.h) and this state is comprised of *position*, *velocity* and *effort*.

The "only" task of the JSC is to take that state, convert it into a [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) message and publish it.

As this "controller" (and I place this in quotes as it doesn't really control anything, but that's just `ros_control` nomenclature) has to do that in a generic way: it cannot know anything about any robot's specific implementation, or we could not all reuse the same JSC. Hiding such details as "ticks" and "encoders" from the JSC (and other controllers in `ros_control`) is the task of the `hardware_interface`.

This piece of the `ros_control` stack is the *interface* to the hardware, and it performs a number of functions:

1. it takes are of converting whatever units the robot hw uses into ROS standard units ([REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html))
2. it provides a way to communicate with the hw (ie: using a serial bus, a fieldbus (ethercat, canbus, powerlink, profinet, profibus, ..), plain ethernet, TCP or UDP sockets, GPIO, direct memory registers, etc, etc)
3. it takes care of any special initialisation routines or procedures that are needed to put the hardware in a state where it can actually be controlled
4. it deals with error handling and recovery

And most (all?) of this is intended to abstract away implementation details about the robot for one purpose: if we hide all (most) knowledge of the actual hardware being used/addressed behind the `hardware_interface`, we can reuse as much of `ros_control` as possible, as none of the controllers (for instance) need to know anything about "encoders", "ticks" or any such things. This is the main idea behind `ros_control` (and in fact all of software engineering where abstraction is used to hide "implementation details" as they are called).

> I'm really confused about what are the data joint_state_controller acquires from the Robot's Encoders, are they ticks, ticks per meter or rad?

I hope you already know the answer to this now, but just to make it clear: they are not ticks, but the units that we've standardised on in ROS. So:

- position: radians or metres (for revolute and prismatic joints respectively)
- velocity: radians/sec or metres/sec (idem)
- effort: Newtons or Newton metres (idem)

The `hardware_interface` will have to already have performed the conversion. And again: this is read from the `hardware_interface`, not encoders or the robot directly.

> and if it was ticks, where can I provide the Radius of the wheels to the Controller?

I hope this one is already clear now as well: the controller does not do any conversion of units, so it does not need to know about ticks or wheel radii.

If you're thinking about odometry, then keep in mind that there are (at least) two levels of sensor data processing here: first from hw specific units to ROS units (reponsibility of the `hardware_interface`) and second from joint state to vehicle state.

In `ros_control`, for wheeled platforms, the latter is typically done by something like the [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller). It is that controller that must know something about wheel radii, as it has to convert joint velocities into vehicle velocities and vice versa (ie: state and setpoints).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-15**:
For some additional words about the `joint_state_controller` and the `joint_state_publisher`, see #q303358.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-15**:
And I don't like linking to off-site resources (as they may change and/or disappear), but perhaps [How to implement ros_control on a custom robot](https://slaterobots.com/blog/5abd8a1ed4442a651de5cb5b/how-to-implement-ros_control-on-a-custom-robot) can also help.

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-15**:
While that guide is definitely a good start. Please be aware that it registers `SoftJointLimits` which are not given in in the `joint_limits.yaml`. Make sure to either not register the softlimits or specify them in your `joint_limits.yaml` as they will otherwise default to 0 and the enforcing of the limits in the `write()` method will not allow you to send position commands other than 0.

I'm not sure if the guide is outdated or simply incomplete but this caused me quite the headache while following it the first time.